# Return an api response from rest controller and then do some processing async

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, asynchronous, spring-async

I am new to spring boot and trying an interesting scenario. I want to return the result of an api and post that do some kafka and rabbitMQ publishing and I don't want my api response to halt till the time I am doing publishing. I am trying to use `@EnableAsync` to enable async processing in the application and `@async` to define my methods.

```
@Async
    fun publishOfferEventsAsync() {
        Thread.sleep(10000)
    // publish to rmq
        logger().debug { "xxxyyyzzz" }
    }
```

Can I directly call this async execution from other non-async methods of the bean?
Is there a better way you can suggest.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both sync. and `@Async` are defined in different objects , it is okay.

If they are defined in the same object , it is not okay simply because spring AOP which `@Async` is based on does not support self-invocation. (Refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/proxying.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) for details)

If they really need to be defined in the same object , you can define another generic `@Async` executor bean and call the async. method via it. Something likes :

```java
@Service
public class AsyncExecutor {

    @Async
    public <T> T execute(Supplier<T> action) {
        return action.get();
    }

    @Async
    public void execute(Runnable action) {
        action.run();
    }

}
```

And then inject it to use it :

```java
@Service
public class FooService {

   @Autowired
   private AsyncExecutor asyncExecutor;

   public void someSyncMethod(){
     asyncExecutor.execute(()->publishOfferEventsAsync());
   }

   @Aysnc 
   public void publishOfferEventsAsync() {
      ...
   }

}
```